# Full width responsive website body image

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am stuck at something.
I need to create a single page website with full width background image, but the image gets cut at each sides when open in the website.

The website is live at [here](http://johnsonorchid.com/)

Currently I am using backstretch. But I have tried with with 100% and custom CSS then effect is either same or worse. Even used cover as background-size.

Is there any way to fix this so that the image should open correctly at mobile?

Comment: Well what will be the goal? U provide a Landscape Image and u want to show it on a portrait view? If so u have to deal with whitespace or a image not displayed right. Use two different Images an select them via media query and than use background-size: cover

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I use the jquery to fix the height according to browser width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am doing it with the help of js.

```
function updateSize() {
    var width = $(window).width();
    var height = $(window).height();

    $('.image-con').css('width', width);
    $('.image-con').css('height', height);
};
$(document).ready(updateSize);
$(window).resize(updateSize);
```

And CSS

```
.image-con {
    background-image: url(bg.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the CSS `background-image` property instead of an actual `img`

```
body{
  background:url(bg.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size:cover !important;
}
```

You'll also find it a lot easier to manipulate your other page elements with a background instead of `img`

Comment: Now see when I open it in iphone I see while space at bottom, which I do not need to be there.

Comment: try adding vendor prefixes. 

-webkit-background-size:cover;
-moz-background-size:cover;
background-size:cover;

Comment: @Varinder Done.. Check.

Comment: @Varinder - Yep, should really have included that. Well spotted! If this fixed it **user2485649**, please mark it as the correct answer. Thanks

Comment: This answer didn't fix the issue @dwhite.me

Answer (score 0):

HTML element ( root ) must have atleast `min-height:100%`

so Markup

```
<html style="min-height:100%; padding:0; margin:0;">
    <body style="margin:0; padding:0; height:100%;"> </body>
</html>
```

oh and yea, once tested, extract those inline styles to a stylesheet

Hope that helps.

**Edit**

heres the best you can do

css:

```
body {
    /*background-attachment: scroll;*/
    /*background-clip: border-box;*/
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    background-image: url("bg.jpg");
    /*background-origin: padding-box;*/
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: 'PetitaBold';
}
```

Comment: Check bro, it still cuts the image :(

Comment: hey man, you cant avoid cutting i guess, edited css to the best you can do

Comment: yes, I think image will be cut of.. I edited it again and sill same.